# Настройка вывода лог сообщения в консоль

Tags: c#, консоль, логирование

Делаю вывод лога так:

```
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
                                  .AddConsole();
ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
logger.LogInformation("This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.");
```

в результате получаю сообщения:

> info: ConsoleLogging.Program[0]
>           This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.

А хотелось бы так:

> info: This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отформатировать вывод логов в консоль?

За основу была взята статья [Протоколирование в .net Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/mt694089.aspx)

Comment: Показали бы реализацию своих `LoggerFactory` и прочих. Если это какой-то сторонний пакет, надо указать какой...

Comment: Использую библиотеки Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console. Данный пример написан в отдельном проекте, и , собственно, это весь код из блока mai.